# Air,in my clutch system

Tags: manual-transmission

I went through all the procedures of bleeding my clutch and slave cyclender and still no clutch pedal at all and everything is all new is there something I'm missing can u please let me know thank  u it's a 97 ford ranger 5 speed 4.0

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "everything is all new", what does "everything" mean? What *exactly* is new?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to bleed the master cylinder. They usually have a bleed screw on the side. Bleed the master cylinder, then bleed the rest of the system.

Like brake systems clutch hydraulics don't spontaneously or intermittently let air in. If you have air in your clutch system you've got problems besides bleeding the clutch. If that problem is still happening you may not be able to bleed successfully until the issue is resolved.

I feel that this is just a symptom of something else. I hope not, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you push the clutch down do you feel the clutch resisting or does it go down really easy?

If it is really easy ie soft then it may be only the return springs in the slave and master cylinders pushing the pedal back up and the clutch cover plate may have failed or has stuck. This needs investigation as to the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

Rangers are particularly hard to bleed the clutch master/slave cylinder, what I do is buy an [old fashioned oil can](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KEJYAY), fill it with brake fluid and pump it a few times to get the air out, connect it to the bleeder on the slave cylinder using a rubber hose (vacuum hose is my favorite) and after opening the bleeder on the slave, pump fluid into the bleeder up into the master cylinder pushing out all the air. You may have to bleed the slave in the normal way after this to get and small amounts of air out of the slave cylinder. Be sure to leave the cap off/loose of the Master cylinder when reverse bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

Brand new master aswell? did you bench bleed it? If thats in line then i would recommend gravity bleeding, did wonders for my z. Open up the slave and just let it drip while keeping the master topped up. after you feel an entire system's worth of oil has dripped through close it up and check the feel